# Creating href links pointing to the associated article in the other language

Tags: articles, language, joomla-3.5

I want to create a href link in my Joomla articles pointing out to the one which is associated with its one. I used to copy an old article and edit its content its time. So I ask if there is any *joomla code* which I can use to the *src* without having to modify it each time. I know that I can do this with jQuery but I prefer use a Joomla way if is any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I used jquery and worked.

Here is the answer:

I added a class "testimonial-crosslink" to my href link in all articles like:

```
<a class="testimonial-crosslink" href="#">here</a>
```

**JS:**

```
var testimonial_crosslink_href = $('.mod-languages ul.lang-inline li:not(.lang-active) a').attr('href');
$('.testimonial-crosslink').attr('href', testimonial_crosslink_href);
```